# Fully generic, very efficient bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, library, dijkstra

After finding out that my previous implementations are incorrect, I decided to give it another try. I relied on [this post](https://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eucahmto/math/2020/05/30/bidirectional-dijkstra.html).

(The entire project resides in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/coderodde/BidirectionalDijkstra.java). Contains some unit tests that are not included in this post.)

## Code

**`com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.BidirectionalDijkstrasAlgorithm.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements a bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm. 
 * 
 * @param <N> the actual graph node type.
 * @param <W> the value type of arc weights.
 */
public final class BidirectionalDijkstrasAlgorithm<N, W> {
    
    /**
     * Searches for a shortest {@code source/target} path. Throws an 
     * {@link IllegalStateException} if the target node is not reachable from 
     * the source node.
     * 
     * @param source           the source node.
     * @param target           the target node.
     * @param childrenExpander the node expander generating child nodes.
     * @param parentsExpander  the node expander generating parent nodes.
     * @param weightFunction   the weight function of the graph.
     * @param scoreComparator  the comparator for comparing weights/node 
     *                         g-scores.
     * 
     * @return the shortest path.
     */
    public List<N> findShortestPath(N source,
                                    N target,
                                    NodeExpander<N> childrenExpander,
                                    NodeExpander<N> parentsExpander,
                                    WeightFunction<N, W> weightFunction,
                                    Comparator<W> scoreComparator) {
        if (source.equals(target)) {
            // We need to handle this special case, since the actual algorithm
            // cannot deal with it.
            return Arrays.asList(target);
        }
        
        Queue<HeapNodeWrapper<N, W>> queueF = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Queue<HeapNodeWrapper<N, W>> queueB = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Map<N, W> distancesF = new HashMap<>();
        Map<N, W> distancesB = new HashMap<>();
        Map<N, N> parentsF = new HashMap<>();
        Map<N, N> parentsB = new HashMap<>();
        Set<N> settledF = new HashSet<>();
        Set<N> settledB = new HashSet<>();
        
        queueF.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(
                weightFunction.getZero(),
                source, 
                scoreComparator));
        
        queueB.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(
                weightFunction.getZero(), 
                target,
                scoreComparator));
        
        distancesF.put(source, weightFunction.getZero());
        distancesB.put(target, weightFunction.getZero());
        
        parentsF.put(source, null);
        parentsB.put(target, null);
        
        W mu = weightFunction.getInfinity();
        N touchNodeF = null;
        N touchNodeB = null;
        
        while (!queueF.isEmpty() && !queueB.isEmpty()) {
            N currentNodeF = queueF.remove().getNode();
            N currentNodeB = queueB.remove().getNode();
            
            settledF.add(currentNodeF);
            settledB.add(currentNodeB);
            
            for (N childNode : childrenExpander.expand(currentNodeF)) {
                if (settledF.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                if (!distancesF.containsKey(childNode) ||
                     scoreComparator.compare(
                           distancesF.get(childNode),        
                           weightFunction.sum(
                                distancesF.get(currentNodeF),
                                weightFunction.getWeight(currentNodeF, 
                                                         childNode))) > 0) {
                    
                    W tentativeDistance = 
                            weightFunction.sum(
                                    distancesF.get(currentNodeF), 
                                    weightFunction.getWeight(currentNodeF, 
                                                             childNode));
                    
                    distancesF.put(childNode, tentativeDistance);
                    parentsF.put(childNode, currentNodeF);
                    queueF.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(tentativeDistance,
                                                     childNode,
                                                     scoreComparator));
                } 
                
                if (settledB.contains(childNode)) {
                    W shortestPathUpperBound = 
                            weightFunction.sum(
                                    distancesF.get(currentNodeF),
                                    weightFunction.getWeight(currentNodeF, 
                                                             childNode),
                                    distancesB.get(childNode));
                    
                    if (scoreComparator.compare(mu, 
                                                shortestPathUpperBound) > 0) {
                        
                        mu = shortestPathUpperBound;
                        touchNodeF = currentNodeF;
                        touchNodeB = childNode;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            for (N parentNode : parentsExpander.expand(currentNodeB)) {
                if (settledB.contains(parentNode)) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                if (!distancesB.containsKey(parentNode) ||
                     scoreComparator.compare(
                           distancesB.get(parentNode),        
                           weightFunction.sum(
                                distancesB.get(currentNodeB),
                                weightFunction.getWeight(parentNode, 
                                                         currentNodeB))) > 0) {
                    
                    W tentativeDistance = 
                            weightFunction.sum(
                                    distancesB.get(currentNodeB), 
                                    weightFunction.getWeight(parentNode,
                                                             currentNodeB));
                    
                    distancesB.put(parentNode, tentativeDistance);
                    parentsB.put(parentNode, currentNodeB);
                    queueB.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(tentativeDistance,
                                                     parentNode,
                                                     scoreComparator));
                } 
                
                if (settledF.contains(parentNode)) {
                    W shortestPathUpperBound = 
                            weightFunction.sum(
                                    distancesF.get(parentNode),
                                    weightFunction.getWeight(parentNode,
                                                             currentNodeB),
                                    distancesB.get(currentNodeB));
                    
                    if (scoreComparator.compare(mu, 
                                                shortestPathUpperBound) > 0) {
                        
                        mu = shortestPathUpperBound;
                        touchNodeF = parentNode;
                        touchNodeB = currentNodeB;
                    }
                }   
            }
            
            if (distancesF.containsKey(currentNodeF) && 
                distancesB.containsKey(currentNodeB) &&
                scoreComparator.compare(
                        weightFunction.sum(
                                distancesF.get(currentNodeF),
                                distancesB.get(currentNodeB)), 
                        mu) > 0) {
                
                return tracebackPath(touchNodeF, 
                                     touchNodeB,
                                     parentsF,
                                     parentsB);
            }
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "The target node is not reachable from the source node.");
    }
    
    private static <N> List<N> tracebackPath(N touchNodeF,
                                             N touchNodeB,
                                             Map<N, N> parentsF,
                                             Map<N, N> parentsB) {
        List<N> path = new ArrayList<>();
        
        N node = touchNodeF;
        
        while (node != null) {
            path.add(node);
            node = parentsF.get(node);
        }
        
        Collections.reverse(path);
        node = touchNodeB;
        
        while (node != null) {
            path.add(node);
            node = parentsB.get(node);
        }
        
        return path;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.DijkstrasAlgorithm.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements the (unidirectional) Dijkstra's algorithm.
 * 
 * @param <N> the actual graph node type.
 * @param <W> the weight value type.
 */
public final class DijkstrasAlgorithm<N, W> {

    /**
     * Finds the shortest {@code source/target} path or throws an 
     * {@link IllegalStateException} if the target node is not reachable from 
     * the source node.
     * 
     * @param source           the source node.
     * @param target           the target node.
     * @param childrenExpander the children expander.
     * @param weightFunction   the graph weight function.
     * @param scoreComparator  the score comparator.
     * 
     * @return the shortest path, if any exist.
     */
    public List<N> findShortestPath(N source,
                                    N target, 
                                    NodeExpander<N> childrenExpander,
                                    WeightFunction<N, W> weightFunction,
                                    Comparator<W> scoreComparator) {
        
        Queue<HeapNodeWrapper<N, W>> open = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Map<N, W> distanceMap             = new HashMap<>();
        Map<N, N> parentMap               = new HashMap<>();
        Set<N> closed                     = new HashSet<>();
        
        open.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(
                weightFunction.getZero(), 
                source, 
                scoreComparator));
        
        distanceMap.put(source, weightFunction.getZero());
        parentMap.put(source, null);
        
        while (!open.isEmpty()) {
            N currentNode = open.remove().getNode();
            
            if (currentNode.equals(target)) {
                return tracebackSolution(target, parentMap);
            }
            
            closed.add(currentNode);
            
            for (N childNode : childrenExpander.expand(currentNode)) {
                if (closed.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }
                
                if (!distanceMap.containsKey(childNode)) {
                    W tentativeDistance = 
                            weightFunction.sum(
                                    distanceMap.get(currentNode),
                                    weightFunction.getWeight(currentNode, 
                                                             childNode));
                    
                    distanceMap.put(childNode, tentativeDistance);
                    parentMap.put(childNode, currentNode);
                    open.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(tentativeDistance, 
                                                   childNode,
                                                   scoreComparator));
                } else {
                    W tentativeDistance = 
                            weightFunction.sum(
                                    distanceMap.get(currentNode),
                                    weightFunction.getWeight(currentNode, 
                                                             childNode));

                    if (scoreComparator.compare(distanceMap.get(childNode), tentativeDistance) > 0) {
                        distanceMap.put(childNode, tentativeDistance);
                        parentMap.put(childNode, currentNode);
                        open.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(tentativeDistance,
                                                      childNode,
                                                      scoreComparator));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Target not reachable from the source.");
    }
    
    private static <N> List<N> tracebackSolution(N target, Map<N, N> parentMap) {
        List<N> path = new ArrayList<>();
        N node = target;
        
        while (node != null) {
            path.add(node);
            node = parentMap.get(node);
        }
        
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.HeapNodeWrapper.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.pathfinding;

import java.util.Comparator;

final class HeapNodeWrapper<N, W> implements Comparable<HeapNodeWrapper<N, W>> {

    private final W score;
    private final N node;
    private final Comparator<W> scoreComparator;
    
    HeapNodeWrapper(W score,
                    N node,
                    Comparator<W> scoreComparator) {
        this.score = score;
        this.node = node;
        this.scoreComparator = scoreComparator;
    }
    
    N getNode() {
        return node;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(HeapNodeWrapper<N, W> o) {
        return scoreComparator.compare(this.score, o.score);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.NodeExpander.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.pathfinding;

import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for all the node expanders.
 * 
 * @param <N> the actual type of the nodes.
 */
public interface NodeExpander<N> {
     
    /**
     * Returns the expansion view of the input node.
     * 
     * @param node the node to expand.
     * @return the collection of "next" nodes to consider in search.
     */
    Collection<N> expand(N node);
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.WeightFunction.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.pathfinding;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for graph weight functions.
 * 
 * @param <N> the actual graph node type.
 * @param <W> the type of the weight values.
 */
public interface WeightFunction<N, W> {
    
    /**
     * Returns the weight of the arc {@code (tail, head)}.
     * 
     * @param tail the starting node of the arc.
     * @param head the ending node of the arc.
     * @return the weight of the input arc.
     */
    W getWeight(N tail, N head);
    
    /**
     * Returns the value of type {@code W} representing zero.
     * 
     * @return the zero value.
     */
    W getZero();
    
    /**
     * Returns the largest representable weight.
     * 
     * @return the largest weight. 
     */
    W getInfinity();
    
    /**
     * Returns the sum of {@code w1} and {@code w2}.
     * 
     * @param w1 the first weight value.
     * @param w2 the second weight value.
     * 
     * @return the sum of the two input weights.
     */
    W sum(W w1, W w2);
    
    /**
     * Returns the sum of three input weights. We need this method primarily for 
     * bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm.
     * 
     * @param w1 the first weight.
     * @param w2 the second weight.
     * @param w3 the third weight.
     * @return the sum of the three input weights.
     */
    default W sum(W w1, W w2, W w3) {
        return sum(w1, sum(w2, w3));
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.benchmark.Benchmark.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.benchmark;

import com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.BidirectionalDijkstrasAlgorithm;
import com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.DijkstrasAlgorithm;
import com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.NodeExpander;
import com.github.coderodde.pathfinding.WeightFunction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

final class Benchmark {
 
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_NODES = 100_000;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_ARCS = 1_000_000;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = parseSeed(args);
        System.out.println("Seed = " + seed);
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        GraphData graphData = getRandomGraph(NUMBER_OF_NODES, 
                                             NUMBER_OF_ARCS, 
                                             random);
        
        System.out.printf("Built the graph in %d milliseconds.\n", 
                          System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        
        DirectedGraphNode source = graphData.getRandonNode(random);
        DirectedGraphNode target = graphData.getRandonNode(random);
        
        System.out.printf("Source node: %s\n", source);
        System.out.printf("Target node: %s\n", target);
        
        DijkstrasAlgorithm<DirectedGraphNode, Float> pathfinderDijkstra =
                new DijkstrasAlgorithm<>();
        
        BidirectionalDijkstrasAlgorithm<DirectedGraphNode, Float> 
                pathfinderBidirectionalDijkstra = 
                new BidirectionalDijkstrasAlgorithm<>();
        
        NodeExpander<DirectedGraphNode> childNodeExpander = 
                new DirectedGraphNodeChildrenExpander();
        
        NodeExpander<DirectedGraphNode> parentNodeExpander = 
                new DirectedGraphNodeParentsExpander();
        
        DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction = 
                new DirectedGraphWeightFunction();
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        List<DirectedGraphNode> pathDijkstra = 
                pathfinderDijkstra.findShortestPath(
                        source, 
                        target,
                        childNodeExpander, 
                        weightFunction,
                        Float::compare);
        
        System.out.printf("Dijkstra's algorithm in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        List<DirectedGraphNode> pathBidirectionalDijkstra = 
                pathfinderBidirectionalDijkstra.findShortestPath(
                        source, 
                        target, 
                        childNodeExpander, 
                        parentNodeExpander,
                        weightFunction, 
                        Float::compare);
        
        System.out.printf(
                "Bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in %d milliseconds.\n",
                System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        
        boolean pathsAreEqual = pathDijkstra.equals(pathBidirectionalDijkstra);
        
        if (pathsAreEqual) {
            System.out.println("Paths agree:");
            
            for (DirectedGraphNode node : pathDijkstra) {
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            
            System.out.printf(
                    "Path cost: %.3f\n", 
                    computePathCost(pathDijkstra, weightFunction));
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Paths diagree!");
            System.out.println("Dijkstra's algorithm's path:");
            
            for (DirectedGraphNode node : pathDijkstra) {
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            
            System.out.printf("Dijkstra's path cost: %.3f\n", 
                              computePathCost(pathDijkstra, weightFunction));
            
            System.out.println("Bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm's path:");
            
            for (DirectedGraphNode node : pathBidirectionalDijkstra) {
                System.out.println(node);
            }
            
            System.out.printf("Bidirectional Dijkstra's path cost: %.3f\n", 
                              computePathCost(pathBidirectionalDijkstra, 
                                              weightFunction));
        }
    }
    
    private static long parseSeed(String[] args) {
        if (args.length == 0) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.printf("WARNING: Could not parse %s as a long value.",
                              args[0]);
            
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    
    private static float computePathCost(
            List<DirectedGraphNode> path,
            DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction) {
        float cost = 0.0f;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size() - 1; i++) {
            DirectedGraphNode tail = path.get(i);
            DirectedGraphNode head = path.get(i + 1);
            float arcWeight = weightFunction.getWeight(tail, head);
            cost += arcWeight;
        }
        
        return cost;
    }
    
    private static final class GraphData {
        private final List<DirectedGraphNode> graphNodes;
        private final DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction;
        
        GraphData(List<DirectedGraphNode> graphNodes,
                  DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction) {
            
            this.graphNodes = graphNodes;
            this.weightFunction = weightFunction;
        }
        
        DirectedGraphNode getRandonNode(Random random) {
            return choose(graphNodes, random);
        }
    }
    
    private static final GraphData 
        getRandomGraph(int nodes, int edges, Random random) {
        
        List<DirectedGraphNode> graph = new ArrayList<>(nodes);
        Set<Arc> arcs = new HashSet<>(edges);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
            graph.add(new DirectedGraphNode());
        }
        
        while (arcs.size() < edges) {
            DirectedGraphNode tail = choose(graph, random);
            DirectedGraphNode head = choose(graph, random);
            Arc arc = new Arc(tail, head);
            arcs.add(arc);
        }
        
        DirectedGraphWeightFunction weightFunction = 
                new DirectedGraphWeightFunction();
        
        for (Arc arc : arcs) {
            DirectedGraphNode tail = arc.getTail();
            DirectedGraphNode head = arc.getHead();
            float weight = 100.0f * random.nextFloat();
            tail.addChild(head, weight);
        }
        
        return new GraphData(graph, weightFunction);
    }
        
    private static <T> T choose(List<T> list, Random random) {
        return list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
        
    private static final class Arc {
        private final DirectedGraphNode tail;
        private final DirectedGraphNode head;
        
        Arc(DirectedGraphNode tail, DirectedGraphNode head) {
            this.tail = tail;
            this.head = head;
        }
        
        DirectedGraphNode getTail() {
            return tail;
        }
        
        DirectedGraphNode getHead() {
            return head;
        }
        
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(tail, head);
        }
        
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Arc arc = (Arc) o;
            return tail.equals(arc.tail) && 
                   head.equals(arc.head);
        }
    }
}

final class DirectedGraphNode {
    
    private static int nodeIdCounter = 0;
    private final int id;
    
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Float> outgoingArcs =
          new HashMap<>();
    
    private final Map<DirectedGraphNode, Float> incomingArcs =
          new HashMap<>();
    
    DirectedGraphNode() {
        this.id = nodeIdCounter++;
    }
    
    void addChild(DirectedGraphNode child, Float weight) {
        outgoingArcs.put(child, weight);
        child.incomingArcs.put(this, weight);
    }
    
    List<DirectedGraphNode> getChildren() {
        return new ArrayList<>(outgoingArcs.keySet());
    }
    
    List<DirectedGraphNode> getParents() {
        return new ArrayList<>(incomingArcs.keySet());
    }
    
    Float getWeightTo(DirectedGraphNode headNode) {
        return outgoingArcs.get(headNode);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[DirectedGraphNode id = %d]", id);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        DirectedGraphNode other = (DirectedGraphNode) obj;
        return this.id == other.id;
    }
}

class DirectedGraphWeightFunction
        implements WeightFunction<DirectedGraphNode, Float> {

    @Override
    public Float getWeight(DirectedGraphNode tail, DirectedGraphNode head) {
        return tail.getWeightTo(head);
    }

    @Override
    public Float getZero() {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public Float getInfinity() {
        return Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    }

    @Override
    public Float sum(Float w1, Float w2) {
        return w1 + w2;
    }
}

class DirectedGraphNodeChildrenExpander 
        implements NodeExpander<DirectedGraphNode> {

    @Override
    public List<DirectedGraphNode> expand(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        return node.getChildren();
    }
}

class DirectedGraphNodeParentsExpander
        implements NodeExpander<DirectedGraphNode> {

    @Override
    public List<DirectedGraphNode> expand(DirectedGraphNode node) {
        return node.getParents();
    }
}
```

## Typical output

```
Seed = 1705171998017
Built the graph in 1768 milliseconds.
Source node: [DirectedGraphNode id = 80226]
Target node: [DirectedGraphNode id = 33520]
Dijkstra's algorithm in 1056 milliseconds.
Bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm in 31 milliseconds.
Paths agree:
[DirectedGraphNode id = 80226]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 35320]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 77598]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 93003]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 34031]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 32260]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 53773]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 53078]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 35871]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 15879]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 79948]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 31828]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 10811]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 44856]
[DirectedGraphNode id = 33520]
Path cost: 123,482
```

## Critique request

As always, I would like to hear whatever comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Not a full review)
A lot of things feel done right - doc comments, use of interfaces, visibility…

One alternative to keeping a set of `closed` nodes should be to keep `open` as a "`PrioritySet`": higher priority offers replacing a node kept, equal or lower ignored.
It doesn't feel quite right to keep a/the Comparator with every NodeWrapper.
What if one extended the priority datastructure to keep it, and made the NodeWrapper a nested class? (Is the design any cleaner? The implicit reference to the enclosing priority DS instance should take as much space an explicit reference to a Comparator.)

Some code in `DijkstrasAlgorithm.findShortestPath()`'s inner loop looks duplicated.
It would seem it might look

```
            for (N childNode : childrenExpander.expand(currentNode)) {
                if (closed.contains(childNode)) {
                    continue;
                }
                W tentativeDistance = weightFunction.sum(
                                distanceMap.get(currentNode),
                                weightFunction.getWeight(currentNode, childNode));
                if (!distanceMap.containsKey(childNode)
                    || scoreComparator.compare(distanceMap.get(childNode),
                                               tentativeDistance) > 0) {
                    distanceMap.put(childNode, tentativeDistance);
                    parentMap.put(childNode, currentNode);
                    open.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(tentativeDistance,
                                                   childNode,
                                                   scoreComparator));
                }
            }
```

In `BidirectionalDijkstrasAlgorithm.findShortestPath()`, I think the declarations "qualified" by `F`&`B` a [code smell](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).
If there was a class subsuming these, it should be possible to remove most code duplication.

```
class ExplorationState {
    Queue<HeapNodeWrapper<N, W>> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    Map<N, W> distances = new HashMap<>();
    Map<N, N> parents = new HashMap<>();
    Set<N> settled = new HashSet<>();
    N touchNode;

    ExplorationState(N start, WeightFunction<N, W> weightFunction,
                     Comparator<W> scoreComparator) {
        queue.add(new HeapNodeWrapper<>(weightFunction.getZero(),
                                        start,
                                        scoreComparator));
        distances.put(start, weightFunction.getZero());
        parents.put(start, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(target)` target not being an array, I suggest `Collections.singletonList(target)`.

Answer (score 2):

I must say that trying to implement Dijkstra's algorithm without introducing the concept of a graph is an interesting one. Having to implement all those lambdas and interfaces separately doesn't seem easier than having to implement the exact same operations in a single `Graph`-interface. Also, a `Graph`-interface would provide a domain specific language, which would make the code much easier to follow and maintain.

A `Graph`-interface would remove the concept of two-way edges from the Dijkstra's algorithm and would make it more generic. You could leave it up to the user to provide a `Graph` that uses either one way or two way edges.

`Parent` and `child` are vocabulary from ordered collections like trees and linked lists. They seem out of place in a graph.

No part of the algorithm has to deal with infinity and zero in the same context. Therefore your weight type does not need to be able to represent either. You can replace them with `null`. This does require a few null-checks in your code but I think the simplicity payoff from removing the requirement of representing zero and infinity from the user makes it worthwhile. Both concepts are internal to the algorithm and there is no guarantee that either can be represented in the actual weight type (for example if an edge represents a road with speed limit). The `WeightFunction` would then become a simple `BiFunction<W, W, W>` (since the `Graph` provides the method for finding the weight between vertexes).

I did write a [generic Dijkstra's algorithm](https://gitlab.com/antti.brax/reinventing-the-wheel/-/blob/main/src/main/java/fi/iki/asb/wheel/algorithm/impl/DijkstraShortestPathSearch.java) myself not so long ago, feel free to check it out.

Comment: Point. Ja, tietenkin, Suomi Perkele! ;-)